# Sendmail: what does nrcpts=0 mean?

Tags: sendmail, log-files

Im attempting to parse some sendmail logs. Im running into lots of apparent emails that have no recipients - or so it would appear.

```
Mar 18 19:12:35 castor sendmail[543]: q2J2CYIv000543: from=<paj@otech.org>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=1, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-SSL, relay=somehost.net [6.7.36.178]
Mar 18 19:12:35 castor sendmail[543]: q2J2CYIw000543: from=<paj@otech.org>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-SSL, relay=somehost.net [6.7.36.178]
Mar 18 19:12:35 castor sendmail[543]: q2J2CYIx000543: from=<paj@otech.org>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-SSL, relay=somehost.net [6.7.36.178]
Mar 18 19:12:35 castor sendmail[543]: q2J2CYJ0000543: from=<paj@otech.org>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-SSL, relay=somehost.net [6.7.36.178]
Mar 18 19:12:35 castor sendmail[543]: q2J2CYJ1000543: from=<paj@otech.org>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-SSL, relay=somehost.net [6.7.36.178]
Mar 18 19:12:35 castor sendmail[543]: q2J2CYJ2000543: from=<paj@otech.org>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-SSL, relay=somehost.net [76.27.206.178]
```

First - it look like these are all from the same PID (543) yet one has 'nrcpts=1' while the rest are zero.
Second - all are 'size=0'

What do these lines indicate? Searching the log doesn't show any other reference to this PID (or whatever it is).

Comment: Just to confirm, is the message id for all of these entries really q2J2CYIv000543?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nrcpts=0` means that the mail was temporarily rejected right after the MAIL FROM: command at the SMTP dialog.

Comment: rejected by another server?

Comment: `grep q2J2CYIv000543 /var/log/mail.log` will tell you. In my logs they are rejected by my servers

Comment: @adamo don't you mean `grep q2J2CYIv000543 /var/log/maillog` (no dot in the middle of the file)?

Comment: @MikeB On my Debian systems it is mail.log. On my BSD ones maillog :)